# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Anon>to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Report>An explicit conversion exists,are you missing a cast?

Tags: .net, linq

How to select specific column from the table? I try this Shows error 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists,are you missing a cast?

```
var query = myRepository.Query().AsQueryable();

query = query.Select(f =>
                        new
                        {
                            f.Name,
                            f.Email,
                            f.Message,
                            f.Succeeded,
                            f.ExecutedOn,
                            f.CreatedOn,
                            f.DeletedOn
                        }).Where(file => file.DeletedOn == null).OrderByDescending(f => f.CreatedOn);

return query.ToList();
```

but when i try this it works,

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.Name))
          {
              query = query.Where(f =>f.Name.Contains(searchModel.Name));
          }
 query = query.Where(file => file.DeletedOn == null).OrderByDescending(file => file.CreatedOn);
```

Comment: What is your question? There are no details regarding what you want. Please provide more details so that some one will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first query is generating an anonymous type.  If you want a list of `Report` objects then the Lambda in your `Select` call has to create a `Report` object, i.e. this:

```
f =>
                        new
                        {
                            f.Name,
                            f.Email,
                            f.Message,
                            f.Succeeded,
                            f.ExecutedOn,
                            f.CreatedOn,
                            f.DeletedOn
                        }
```

should be this:

```
f =>
                        new Report
                        {
                            f.Name,
                            f.Email,
                            f.Message,
                            f.Succeeded,
                            f.ExecutedOn,
                            f.CreatedOn,
                            f.DeletedOn
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make new Class object and then use it

```
var result = from mr in myRepository
                     where mr.DeletedOn == null
                     orderby mr.CreatedOn descending
                     select new NewRepository
                     {
                          mr.Name,
                    mr.Email,
                    mr.Message,
                    mr.Succeeded,
                    mr.ExecutedOn,
                    mr.CreatedOn,
                   mr.DeletedOn
                     };
```

**if u have any error then let me know ur myRepository DataType**

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized query with type of `IQueryable<Query>` but later assigned with the value of type `IOrderedQueryable<AnonymousType>`, as both types do not match, it will cause compile time error. The problem here is with internal types (`Query`, `AnonymousType`). Please modify your query as below.

```
var query = myRepository.Query().AsQueryable()
                .Select(f =>
                    new
                    {
                        f.Name,
                        f.Email,
                        f.Message,
                        f.Succeeded,
                        f.ExecutedOn,
                        f.CreatedOn,
                        f.DeletedOn
                    }).Where(file => file.DeletedOn == null).OrderByDescending(f => f.CreatedOn);

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: That's not correct.  `IOrderedQueryable<T>` inherits `IQueryable<T>` so there's no issue assigning an instance of the former to a variable of the latter type.  It would not work the other way around, but that's not an issue here.  Look at the error message in the title; the difference is the generic type of the `IQueryable`.

Comment: Please see my edited answer, earlier also i mentioned the same but because of < and > symbol behavior in html it is not showm in my answer and internal types i.e Anon and Report were not mentioned in question at the time of answering it.